# How to write If statement and For loop programatically with Robot Framework API

Tags: python, loops, robotframework

I have been exploring Robot framework and came across this example which I am trying to use. This example works great except I wanted to try adding a for loop and if statement. I haven't even began the if statement yet as I am stuck with the for loop. Please may I have help to suggest how to construct a for loop and if statement.

This is a basic attempt of a for loop to add at the end of the script to test:

```
test.keywords.create('For', args=['1','IN','10'], type='for')
error - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flavor'
```

The code below just shows i am trying to add basic for loop but compiles with above error

```
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
suite.imports.library('OperatingSystem')
test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])
test.keywords.create('Set Environment Variable', args=['SKYNET', 'activated'], type='setup')
test.keywords.create('Environment V`enter code here`ariable Should Be Set', args=['SKYNET'])
test.keywords.create('For', args=['1','IN','10'], type='for')
```

origin - https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/2.8.1/autodoc/robot.running.html

```
test.keywords.create('Create List', args=['a', 'b', 'c'], assign=['@{list}'])
for_kw = ForLoop(['${l}'], ['@{list}'], flavor='IN')
for_kw.keywords.create('log', args=['${l}'])
test.keywords.create()
test.keywords.append(for_kw)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: With Robot Framework this has changed and became easier to do.

Release note: [Running and result models have been changed](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-4.0.rst#running-and-result-models-have-been-changed).

> - `TestSuite`, `TestCase` and `Keyword` objects used to have keywords attribute containing keywords used in them. This name is misleading
>   now when they also have FOR and IF objects. With `TestCase` and
>   `Keyword` the attribute was renamed to `body` and with `TestSuite` it
>   was removed altogether. The keywords attribute still exists but it is
>   read-only and deprecated.
> - The new `body` does not have `create()` method for creating keywords, like the old keywords had, but instead it has separate
>   `create_keyword()`, `create_for()` and `create_if()` methods. This
>   means that old usages like `test.keywords.create()` need to be changed
>   to `test.body.create_keyword()`.

For examples check out this other answer: [How to write FOR loop and IF statement programmatically with Robot Framework 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66705602/3820025).

---

### BEFORE Robot Framework 4.0:

### `IF` statement

The `if` statement should be a `Run Keyword If` keyword with the arguments you need. It is a keyword like any other so you should list everything else in its `args` list.

- The condition.
- The keyword name for the `True` branch.
- Separately any `args` to the keyword for the `True` branch if there is any. Listed separately.

---

- The `ELSE IF` keyword if needed.
- The `ELSE IF` condition.
- The keyword name for the `ELSE IF` branch.
- Separately any `args` to the keyword for the `ELSE IF` branch if there is any. Listed separately.

---

- The `ELSE` keyword.
- The keyword name for the `ELSE` branch.
- Separately any `args` to the keyword for the `ELSE` branch if there is any. Listed separately.

```python
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])

test.keywords.create('Run Keyword If', args=[True, 'Log To Console', 'Condition was TRUE', 'ELSE', 'Log To Console', 'Condition was FALSE'])
test.keywords.create('Run Keyword If', args=[False, 'Log To Console', 'Condition was TRUE', 'ELSE', 'Log To Console', 'Condition was FALSE'])

suite.run()
```

This is how it looks like in the logs:

[image]

---

### `FOR` loop

As for the `for` loop. It is a special keyword implemented by [`robot.running.model.ForLoop`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.ForLoop) class that bases on the `robot.running.model.Keyword` class. Here is the constructor:

> [image]

It has a `flavor` parameter, which is the loop type to be say. So it is `IN`, `IN RANGE`, `IN ZIP`, etc.

Now you instantiating a `robot.running.model.Keyword` which despite you could set its type to `for`, it won't have `flavor` attribute. So when you execute your code it will throw the error you see. It is because the `ForRunner` will try to access the `flavor` attribute.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/running/steprunner.py", line 52, in run_step
    runner = ForRunner(context, self._templated, step.flavor)
AttributeError: 'Keyword' object has no attribute 'flavor'
```

So you have to use the `ForLoop` class. Also I am using Robot Framework 3.1.2 so the errors might be different in my case but the approach should be the same.

Here is how it should look like:

```python
from robot.running.model import ForLoop

for_kw = ForLoop(['${i}'], ['10'], flavor='IN RANGE')
test.keywords.append(for_kw)
```

No this will still fail with error:

> FOR loop contains no keywords.

So you have to populate it like:

```python
for_kw.keywords.create('No Operation')
```

The complete example:

```python
from robot.api import TestSuite
from robot.running.model import ForLoop

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])
test.keywords.create('Log Many', args=['SKYNET', 'activated'], type='setup')
test.keywords.create('Log', args=['SKYNET'])

for_kw = ForLoop(['${i}'], ['10'], flavor='IN RANGE')
for_kw.keywords.create('No Operation')
test.keywords.append(for_kw)
suite.run()
```

If you run this it will only produce an output XML, you have to run rebot manually to have a log and report HTML file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bence, this is much appreciated... it works perfectly. i will attempt the if then else statement except i am aware of the run keyword if and i assume i will have to go the route you pointed out by using the constructor for the if statement as run.keyword.create can only accept 1 args parameter and not sure how to cator for the else. i have also updated my post with code to iterate through a list

Comment: Thank you @ Bence Kaulics, i have tested and answer works like a charm and i have upvoted and accepted. appreciated

Comment: @Wizard Robot Framework 4.0 is released and much of what is described in my answer have changed. I have updated it.

Comment: thank you for update. i did get deprecation error and .body resolved that and am currently exploring the for and if. wish they included a while but i am trying to make some complex examples with these like a nested if, and a for loop that reads x variables in a list until all of x is captured and validate each x with if statement against a condition. i will share once i figure out. Pls share if you already have examples. thank you

Comment: also looking through libraries to find if any improvements to get variable from python script into testsuite and variable value like the list out of testsuite and into python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699141/how-to-write-for-loop-and-if-statement-programmatically-with-robotframework-4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66702996/with-robotframework-4-is-it-possible-to-get-values-in-and-out-from-body-into-py