# How to write FOR loop and IF statement programmatically with Robot Framework 4.0?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, robotframework

```python
    bot.body.create_keyword('Create List', args=['a', 'b', 'c'], assign=['@{list}'])
    bot.body.create_for(flavor='IN', variables=['${x}'], values=['@{list}'])
    bot.body.create_keyword('log', args=['${x}'])
```

an example which yielded undesired results. I was hoping that it would have run log 3 times but it just logs latest value of x which is `c`. I am trying to make some complex examples with these like a nested if, and a for loop that reads x variables in a list until all of x is captured and validate each x with if statement against a condition. A while loop would have been good but I guess a for if would work.

how to do if statement like this example with create if ?

```
bot.body.create_keyword('Create List', args=['a', 'b', 'c'], assign=['@{list}'])
for_kw = bot.body.create_for(flavor='IN', variables=['${x}'], values=['@{list}'])
for_kw.body.create_keyword(if list[x] == 'b':
            log list[x] (or do any other keyword)
                     elif list[x] == 'c':
            log list[x]
                     else:
            end for loop)
```

There is an extension to this to when we do not know the number of items in the list. how to code this with keywords -

run loop,
pick up items from a file and add to a list,
until no items to pick up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `Log` keyword in the `body` of the `FOR` keyword, currently you are creating it in the `body` of the test case. With the `IF` you have to call the `create_if()` without parameters, then on its returned object you could call `create_branch(type='IF', condition='"${x}" == "b"')` with type and condition. It will return an object of which `body` should be used to add keywords to be executed inside this `IF` branch.

```pyton
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])

test.body.create_keyword('Create List', args=['a', 'b', 'c'], assign=['@{list}'])
for_kw = test.body.create_for(flavor='IN', variables=['${x}'], values=['@{list}'])
for_kw.body.create_keyword('log', args=['${x}'])

if_kw = for_kw.body.create_if()

if_branch = if_kw.body.create_branch(type='IF', condition='"${x}" == "b"')
if_branch.body.create_keyword('log', args=['BBBB'])

elif_branch = if_kw.body.create_branch(type='ELSE IF', condition='"${x}" == "a"')
elif_branch.body.create_keyword('log', args=['AAAA'])

else_branch = if_kw.body.create_branch(type='ELSE', condition='"${x}" == "c"')
else_branch.body.create_keyword('log', args=['CCCC'])

suite.run()
```

For a nested `IF` and `FOR` statements, just repeat the same. Get the body of the keyword and then call `create_if`, `create_for`, etc.

```pyton
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])

test.body.create_keyword('Create List', args=['a', 'b', 'c'], assign=['@{list}'])
for_kw = test.body.create_for(flavor='IN', variables=['${x}'], values=['@{list}'])
for_kw.body.create_keyword('log', args=['${x}'])

for_kw2 = for_kw.body.create_for(flavor='IN', variables=['${x}'], values=['@{list}'])
for_kw2.body.create_keyword('log', args=['${x}'])

suite.run()
```