# With Robot Framework 4.0 is it possible to get values in and out from .body into python script and from python script into .body test suite?

Tags: python, robotframework

```
bot.body.create_keyword('Create List', args=['a', 'b', 'c'], assign=['@{list}'])
bot.body.create_for(flavor='IN', variables=['${x}'], values=['@{list}'])
bot.body.create_keyword('log', args=['${x}'])
```

How to get value `@list` out of this keyword and into python script but without creating new keyword in another python script. example like this:

```
list = bot.body.create_keyword('Create List', args=['a', 'b', 'c'], assign=['@{list}'])
print(list) # and this will print in console and not in output.xml and in the order of execution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot do this. The problem is that you are creating a test case programmatically, you just define a step `Create List` but it is not executed at that point, so the list is not created, there is no execution context.

The `create_keyword` function returns the keyword object not the return value of the inner Robot Framework keyword. Again that is not executed here, the list will be created when you call the `suite.run()`.

You could try with a listener maybe or `Log To Console` but both of these will be invoked during execution as well.

Comment: Yes i guess then there is no way as the testcase will always be only within the suite when it been run. if there was then it would have been great as we could use native python to manipulate data except the next obstacle would be having the native python run in order of execution with suite.run(). will keep trying thou as there might be api extensions in future with this capability